# Incompatible types List of List and ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, incomplete-type

The below line gives me error :

```
Incompatible Types.

List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

What is the reason?

**EDIT**

I understand if I change my second ArrayList to List, it does not give me error. I want to know the reason of error though. Thanks

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();` is valid

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you had a `List<List<Integer>>` then you'd be able to add a `LinkedList<Integer>` to it.  But you can't do this for an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, so the latter can't possibly be a type of `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 37):

The correct writing should be:
`List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`
Since in this way, you can add not only `ArrayList` but also `LinkedList` to `ret`

Answer (score 34):

#### From [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

> This is a common misunderstanding when it comes to programming with
> generics, but it is an important concept to learn.
>
> [image]
>
> `Box<Integer>` is not a subtype of Box even though Integer is a subtype of Number.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question is "what is the reason?".  All you've done is restate the question's premise, using different classes.

Answer (score 13):

The reason is that *generics are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).*

Consider simpler case:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = integers; // cannot do this
numbers.add(new Float(1337.44));
```

Now List holds a Float, which is certainly bad.

Same for your case.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
List<List<Integer>> ll = al; // cannot do this
ll.add(new LinkedList<Integer>())
```

Now you have a list `ll` which holds `LinkedList`, but the `al` is declared as a List of `ArrayList`s.

Comment: Languages without mutation get to have much more fun with polymorphism.

Answer (score 7):

It is clearly stated in [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

> In general, if Foo is a subtype (subclass or subinterface) of Bar, and
>   G is some generic type declaration, **it is not the case that `G<Foo>` is
>   a subtype of `G<Bar>`**. This is probably the hardest thing you need to
>   learn about generics, because it goes against our deeply held
>   intuitions.

Same thing happens here it's `Bar = List<Integer>` and `Foo = ArrayList<Integer>` as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is not sub type of `List<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 6):

Less text more fixes:

```java
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```java
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Comment: The question is "what is the reason".

Answer (score 0):

Before you use generics, you should know 2 principles.

**1. The generics parameter should be the same like:**

```
LinkedList<String> res = new LinkedList<String>();
```

**2. The parameter should directly inherit from class Object like Integer, Character, and List or Array. (LinkedList is the subclass of List, so cannot be the parameter of generics)**

Here is a correct demonstrations:

```
LinkedList<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```