# How to return a super class in a Android Room query?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I am generating multiple types of reports (day, week, month) from a SQL query. The reports have the same attributes but cover a different period and have common structure for their title. To solve this issue I have used the `Report` as a abstract class which defines the attributes and required methods.

My goal is to structure my code in a way that I can use the Report class to benefit from polymorphism. I want to be able to convert the subclasses back to the original superclass so that my `PagedListAdapter` can handle multiple types of reports. How can I accomplish this? I have been trying to use wildcard but without success.

The reason that I am replacing the `LiveData` instance is to make sure only one `LiveData` is subscribed to the `PagedListAdapter`.

**ReportDao.java**

```
@Dao
public abstract class ReportDao {

    @Query(...)
    abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Week> getWeekReports();

    @Query(...)
    abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Month> getMonthReports();

    @Query(...)
    abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Year> getYearReports();

}
```

**ReportsViewModel**

```
public class ReportsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final int TYPE_WEEK = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_MONTH = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_YEAR = 2;

    private final ReportDao reportDao;

    private LiveData<PagedList<Report>> reports;

    public ReportsViewModel(ReportDao reportDao) {
        this.reportDao = reportDao;
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<Report>> getReports(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_WEEK:
                reports = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(reportDao.getWeekReports(), 20)
                        .build(); // this wont compile
            case TYPE_MONTH:
                ....
        }

        return reports;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact compile error that you get?

Comment: @CommonsWare 'incompatible Types'. Well, not really a compiler error but the IDE shows it before even trying to compile.

Comment: My guess is that you are running into [the classic Java covariance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796474/115145). You cannot assign a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>` variable, as `List<Animal>` implies that you can add a `new Cat()` to it, and a `List<Dog>` does not like cats. With something like a `List`, you can always build a replacement list yourself with the correct type (e.g., build an `ArrayList<Animal>` and populate it with your dogs). However, I don't know how you will do that with a `DataSource.Factory`.

Comment: FWIW, I filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78317963) related to this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Your are truly amazing! Thank you! I will follow the issue.

Comment: Yiğit's comment in that issue compiles for me, though I'm not in position right this moment to do a full test.