# List<parent> List<child> inheritance solution

Tags: java, list, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

So I am working on my code and trying to apply abstract factory design pattern into it. Here's the situation.

I have a parent class `CheckList` and a child class `ShoppingList`. Aside from this, I also have `ShoppingListItem`class which extended from `ListItem`class.

```
public abstract class CheckList {
    String name;
    ArrayList<ListItem> items;

    public String getName() { return this.name; };
    public ArrayList<ListItem> getItems() { return this.items; };

    public String setName(String name) { return this.name = name; };

    public abstract void addItem(String name);

    public boolean editItem(String oldName, String newName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName() == oldName) {
                items.get(i).setName(newName);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean deleteItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName() == name) {
                items.remove(i);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean completeItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName() == name) {
                items.get(i).setCompleted();
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }
}


public class ShoppingList extends CheckList {

    public ShoppingList (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = new ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name) {
        // add a new ShoppingListItem to items
        items.add(new ShoppingListItem(name));
    }
}
```

The issue I have here is that

> ```
> ShoppingList.java:9: error: incompatible types:
> ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> cannot be converted to ArrayList<ListItem>
>                 this.items = new ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>();
> ```

Looks like that Java does not allow this kind of inheritance between `ArrayList<parent>` and `ArrayList<child>`. I am wondering if there any solution for this? I am trying to make `ShoppingList` only has a `ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>` and also inherited all the add/delete/etc methods. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Here's my code after revising based on Konstantin Pozhidaev's answer. (I will be working on compacting it soon after I figure this out).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

// CheckList.java
public abstract class CheckList <T extends ListItem> {
    String name;
    ArrayList<T> items;

    public String getName() { return this.name; };
    public ArrayList<T> getItems() { return this.items; };

    public String setName(String name) { return this.name = name; };

    public abstract void addItem(String name);

    public boolean editItem(String oldName, String newName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(oldName)) {
                items.get(i).setName(newName);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean deleteItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                items.remove(i);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean completeItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                items.get(i).setCompleted();
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }
}

// ShoppingList.java
public class ShoppingList extends CheckList<ShoppingListItem> {

    public ShoppingList (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = new ArrayList<ShoppingListItem>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name) {
        // add a new ShoppingListItem to items
        items.add(new ShoppingListItem(name));
    }
}

// ListItem.java
public abstract class ListItem {
    String name;
    boolean completed;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public boolean getStatus() { return this.completed; }

    public void setName(String newName) { this.name = newName; }
    public void setCompleted() { this.completed = true; }
}

// ShoppingListItem.java
public class ShoppingListItem extends ListItem {
    private String name;
    private boolean completed;

    public ShoppingListItem(String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(this.name);
        this.completed = false;
    }
}
```

However, my code broke all my old JUnit cases. Here's one of my sample tests:

```
@Test public void testShoppingListAddItem() {
    User userUnderTest = new User("Shen");

    // groceries list items
    userUnderTest.createShoppingList("Groceries");
    ShoppingList groceries = userUnderTest.getShoppingList().get(0);
    groceries.addItem("Apple");
    groceries.addItem("Banana");
    ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> groceriesItems = groceries.getItems();

    // house renovations list items
    userUnderTest.createShoppingList("House Renovation");
    ShoppingList hr = userUnderTest.getShoppingList().get(1);
    hr.addItem("Paint");
    hr.addItem("Flooring");
    ArrayList<ShoppingListItem> hrItems = hr.getItems();

    // assertions
    assertEquals("the first item suppose to be Apple", 
        "Apple", groceriesItems.get(0).getName());
    assertEquals("the second item suppose to be Banana", 
        "Banana", groceriesItems.get(1).getName());

    assertEquals("the first item suppose to be Paint", 
        "Paint", hrItems.get(0).getName()); 
    assertEquals("the second iten suppose to be Flooring", 
        "Flooring", hrItems.get(1).getName()); 
}
```

Error output:

```
> java.lang.AssertionError: the first item suppose to be Apple
> expected:<Apple> but was:<null>
```

I think the issue is still in my inheritance but I cannot find out where. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796273/incompatible-types-list-of-list-and-arraylist-of-arraylist

Comment: you can try to define the list with wildcard `ArrayList<? extends ListItem> items;`

Comment: Why aren't you just using the diamond operator? `new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic you mean in `CheckList`? Sorry I don't get it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use `ArrayList<? extends ListItem>` instead of `ArrayList<ListItem>` on abstract class.

Also use `equals` method for string comparing.

**UPDATE**

Your abstract class should be look like:

```java
abstract class CheckList<T extends ListItem> {
   ArrayList<T> items;
   ArrayList<T> getItems() { return this.items; }
...
```

The implementation

```java
public class ShoppingList extends CheckList<ShoppingListItem> {
```

You should determinate your generic class for strict class using.

Full listing:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class CheckList<T extends ListItem> {
    String name;
    ArrayList<T> items;

    String getName() { return this.name; }
    ArrayList<T> getItems() { return this.items; }

    public String setName(String name) { return this.name = name; }

    public abstract void addItem(String name);

    public boolean editItem(String oldName, String newName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(oldName)) {
                items.get(i).setName(newName);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean deleteItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                items.remove(i);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }

    public boolean completeItem(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            if (items.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
                items.get(i).setCompleted(true);
                return true; // target found
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot find the target
    }
}

class ListItem {
    private String name;
    private Boolean completed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Boolean getCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCompleted(Boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }
}

class ShoppingListItem extends ListItem {
    public ShoppingListItem(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }
}
public class ShoppingList extends CheckList<ShoppingListItem> {

    public ShoppingList (String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name) {
        // add a new ShoppingListItem to items
        final ShoppingListItem item = new ShoppingListItem(name);
        this.items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did what you said and it shows me error: no suitable method found for add(ShoppingListItem)
                items.add(new ShoppingListItem(name));

Comment: @ProgrammingDonkey Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not inheritence between `GenericClass<Parent>` and `GenericClass<Child>`, but there is a solution for your situation, wildcards:

```
ArrayList<? extends ListItem> items = new ArrayList<>(); //list with wildcard
```

You will be able to put anything that extends `ListItem` into this.

Also consider making your loops a bit more compact using foreach loops, or even better, lambda expressions. For example your delete method:

```
public boolean deleteItem(String name) {
    boolean removed = false;
    items.removeIf(item -> {
       item.getName().equals(name);
       removed = true;
    });
    return removed;
}
```

You should compare strings with the `equals` method by the way.